# Why is my Remix online IDE's screen flickering?

Tags: remix

Whenever I type something in the Remix ONLINE IDE, the entire code flickers. What I mean is that say the keyword `function` is shown in blue color, now when I start typing that blue color will turn to white and then the blue very fast (flickering).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and couldn't find a reson. But if you reload the page it stops flickering.